# Эмуляция простой DoS атаки

Tags: сеть, dos-атака

Пинговал одну из машин командой `ping IP -t -l 65000`. В диспетчере задач добился 100% забитости сети, но сеть почему-то продолжала работать нормально. Сеть 100 Мбит подключена через `router/hub`. Посмотрел загруженность сети на другом хосте показывает ноль загруженности. Как можно посадить локалку в 100 Мбит? Как можно это сделать с локалкой в 1 Гбит?

Comment: Хочу проникнуть в суть...

Comment: Никак, с помощью банального пинга. 43 фрейма по сети в секунду - это такая мелочь

Comment: а что можно сделать? может есть какой то более эффективный способ?

Comment: Причём тут операционная система DOS? Метка не по теме.

Comment: для справки - dos атака это если с 1ого компа, если компов больше то это уже ddos...

Реализация и цели у них довольно таки разные... Вас точно именно dos Интересует?

Comment: да именно ДоС, просто в будущем подразумевается установка ПО на несколько хостов которая и позволит ссимулировать ДДоС атаку.

Comment: DoS (от англ. Denial of Service — отказ в обслуживании) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0

По теме. Если есть возможность качать файлы с хоста (p2p, ftp, http etc) которому надо забить канал, просто качайте файлы в овер 100 потоков и все, канал будет забит

Answer (score 1):

Так как я не могу коментить я прокоментирую ответом .
Вы ошибаетесь или просто что то недоговариваете завалить машину 1 пинговской командой нереально.В вашем случае нужно примерно одновременно запустить так с компов 100 одновременно тогда может и получится.Чтобы вывести из строя средний современный сервер хакеры  заражают несколько тысяч компов вирусом который дает возможность атаковать сервер одновременно всеми зараженными компьютерами .Советую забыть про пингование это неэффективно и давно в прошлом

Comment: а что можете предложить?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите программу на `c++`, которая будет послыать 1000 пакетов в секунду, или найдите похожее что-то в интернете, желательно исходники. Впишите IP-адрес, который нужно досить и досьте на здоровье. Могу дать начало мысли - искать нужно уроки по TCP/UDP протоколам.

Comment: Есть готовые сервисы и это тема не новая, и вообще 1 комп для ДДОС атаки не годится, обычно бот-сети насчитывают от 500 до пару тысяч зомби-машин

Comment: Согласен, проще написать бот-сеть, который будет заражать компы зашедших на сайт, и через их айпишники гасить нужный сервер.

Comment: может проще тогда поставить какойто лайфсиди фриБСД или чего-то юниксового и он туда просто пинговать? (там можно очень гибко конфигурировать размеры, количество и тд пинга)

Comment: Ну если подумать то Вам нужно почитать немного о сокетах и о udp пакетах. Можно написать на с++ или qt или же вообще просто на c# почитайте в интернете

Comment: какой запрос можно дать в поисковике по этому поводу для языка с++?

Comment: http://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B8+udp+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+c%2B%2B&pbx=1&oq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B8+udp+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B+c%2B%2B&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2162l5440l0l5678l14l11l1l0l0l8l264l2164l0.4.7l12l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=84d24d6baea54584&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=799

Comment: ребят а методику проведения Дос ДДос атак где можно взять?

Comment: http://bloggik.net/index.php/downloads/39-networks-soft/115-sprut-dos-atacker

Comment: благодарю. вообще суть заключается в разработке методики и ПО для тестирования оборудования на уязвимость и стойкость к Дос и ДДоС атакам. Буду рад если буду предложения и оказание помощи...

Comment: @Pentium, вы бы сразу вопрос так поставили - он бы решился намного быстрее) Хакеры все-таки не так распространены, как тестеры и спецы по безопасности.

Comment: молодо-зелено.... не смог сформулировать конкретно. думаю теперь мне помогут, убедившись что я изучаю лишь в хороших целях.